# Android fragment creation takes much time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments

I need to make a fragment with hidden panel that can be shown on button click. My layout is a relative layout, main layout is shown by deafault, and the panel is centered and `invisible`.
After adding a panel to layout its loading takes much more time.
Please tell me how to add a panel in an optimized way to show it as a popup.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.SourcesFragment">

    
    <!--    Main layout   -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/sources_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sources_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/button_add"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/selector_button_upgrade_text"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button_build"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button_upgrade"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>



        </ScrollView>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- Hidden panel that is shown onclick   -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/shop_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_margin="20dp"

            android:background="@color/top_bar_color"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="24dp">

                <include layout="@layout/view_source_shop" />

                <include layout="@layout/view_source_shop" />

                <include layout="@layout/view_source_shop" />
                <include layout="@layout/view_source_shop" />
                <include layout="@layout/view_source_shop" />
                <include layout="@layout/view_source_shop" />
                <include layout="@layout/view_source_shop" />
                <include layout="@layout/view_source_shop" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_close"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sources, container, false).apply {
            sourcesParent = findViewById(R.id.sources_parent)
            sourcesLayout = findViewById(R.id.sources_layout)
            shopLayout = findViewById(R.id.shop_layout)
            findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_build).setOnClickListener(::switchShopView)
            findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.button_close).setOnClickListener(::switchShopView)
        }

        Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(object: TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                activity?.runOnUiThread {
                    sourceElements.forEach {
                        it.value.updateView()
                    }
                } ?: cancel()
            } }, 0, 1 * 1000.toLong()
        )

        return view
    }
```

I dont do any operations that can slow down Fragment creation in `onCreateView`.

[image]

You can see the layout included via `include` tag on an image